# Update column for a quick analysis

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I need to remove the last character from one column without updating the table.
How would I do it?
This is what I have tried so far:

```
`set barcode = replace(barcode, right(barcode,1),'') as test from 
 outerbarcodes`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use select rather than set - and you may also try using substring() instead of replace()

```
select barcode, substring(barcode,1,length(barcode)-1) as test from 
outerbarcodes
```

Comment: Hi, just curious. Why substring instead of replace? and I have tried the code above.. it returned the column 'Barcode' and new column 'Test' with no changes in both.

Comment: it's another way - this does not mean that replace() will not work - as I've mentioned you may also try @Eduards

Comment: and what does the number '2' represent `substring(barcode,2,length(barcode)-1) `

Comment: @Eduards, no it should be 1, 1 means the starting position

Comment: perfect! could you explain the code please? im altering the number 1 you have adjusted from 2. Im kinda confused how this code works

Comment: substring function takes 3 parameter - one is string which you want to work with, in your case barcode, startposition will be 1, and number of character you want to extract - as you don't need the last character so length(barcode)-1 has used here - that's it @Eduards

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to do a `SELECT`?

`SELECT replace(barcode, right(barcode,1),'') AS test from outerbarcodes`